# Don't use NAA, rather custom flag, when it's too technical?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

I've got my NAA flag declined (not sure how to link it, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1997232?group=1&status=3) it is amoung others, look for 4th Jan 2018 one).

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48099118/1997232) is in fact a detailed instruction of how to enable tracing, which may or may not help to find reason of the problem, so it's totally irrelevant to this specific question, or saying otherwise - it can apply to whole lot of questions.

I understand, to moderator it may looks like "an attempt" to answer. For me - it should be a comment.

My questions:

- Should I use "custom" flag and explain why it's NAA in such case?
- The answer ([timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48099118/timeline)) go into [LQP queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18425957), got downvote there and then was deleted by OP. Is it correct? I am not sure if downvote is mine.
- Was LQP triggered by my flag? How: directly or indirectly by moderator after he declined my flag?

P.S.: I've read [rtfm](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/1997232) and the case is not there, this is why I am asking.

Comment: Your flag history is only visible to you and the moderators, so the first link isn't very useful.

Answer (score 5):

If you think that an answer is an attempt to answer the question, but that it fails to answer the question adequately, then you should be downvoting it.  Such an answer doesn't merit flagging at all, because it is an answer.  The way that you express your opinions about the technical merits of an answer is by voting, so the fact that you feel that a judgement of the technical merits of the post is relevant *necessarily* precludes any flags being appropriate.

Comment: Exactly. An attempt, no matter how incompetent, to solve the problem *is* an answer. These things aren't answers: "I like pie", "How about them Mets?", "epaeouieptamapomspohmsrtstg;aw". This *is* an answer, although almost surely a very bad one: "Reticulate the spline because strings are mutable in Java. Make sure to change your desktop wallpaper to a blank page and press the space bar repeatedly."

Comment: @RobertColumbia how come "I like pie" isn't an answer? It's an answer to several questions from "What do you like?" to "Which you would prefer between pie or pancake?".

Comment: Technically, it should be a comment. It wouldn't fit though due to amount of content and the OP didn't mention it (but I believe that's why he posted such answer). So I was rather judging this choice "comment vs answer" with flag: "no, it's not an answer". Though I see your point. I shouldn't. Downvote (to *teach* OP not to do this) should be enough. And despite such answer can apply to any question regarding binding problems in wpf, he won't do it. Thanks.

Comment: Though I still have question regarding mechanics. What was with LQP? Whos downvote was it?